# Convert SVG that has an Arabic text to png (or any raster)

Tags: linux, centos, imagemagick, svg

I have an SVG file which has Arabic texts. When I tried to convert it to a raster format Arabic text became unicode signs. Latin letters are allright. I tried imageMagick and rsvg-convert. Both are the same. OS CentOS 6.2.
http://test.pidizayn.com/q/svg-example.zip

Answer (score 1):

Use Inkscape to convert SVG to PNG
Inkscape supports command line.
Below is the command for converting SVG to PNG. I have successfully converted the SVG to PNG.

```
inkscape --without-gui --file=kv.svg --export-area-drawing --export-area-page --export-dpi=300 --export-png=kv.png
```